Bitshift in a bitmap calculation doesn't seem to work
I have a CLI chess program that takes in input from user(eg: 'e2e4') and converts it into two bitmaps i.e., s_map and e_map. 
The bitmaps are represented like 0x0000000000000000ULL;
where the rightmost bit represents h8, leftmost bit represent a1.
The algorithm I used

#ifdef _WIN32
#define CLR "cls"
#else
#define CLR "clear"
#endif
#define SQS 64
#define ROW 8

typedef struct {
    uint64_t wp;
    uint64_t wr;
    uint64_t wn;
    uint64_t wb;
    uint64_t wq;
    uint64_t wk;
    uint64_t bp;
    uint64_t br;
    uint64_t bn;
    uint64_t bb;
    uint64_t bq;
    uint64_t bk;
} PieceBitmaps;
typedef struct {
    uint64_t s_map, e_map;
} Move;
typedef struct {
    uint64_t s_map, e_map;
} Move;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char turn = 'W';
    char winner = ' ';
    PieceBitmaps pieces = init_bitmap();
    Move input;
    while (winner == ' ') {
        system(CLR);
        print_stuff(turn, &pieces);
        do {
            input = get_input();
            printf("Hex: S-map: %x E-map: %x\n", input.s_map, input.e_map);
        } while (1); // TODO: Validity functions go here.
        turn = (turn == 'W') ? 'B' : 'W'; 
    }
}

Move input_to_bitmap(char* input) {
    Move mv;
    mv.s_map = 0x8000000000000000ULL >> (((input[1] - '1') * ROW) + (tolower(input[0]) - 'a'));
    mv.e_map = 0x8000000000000000ULL >> (((input[3] - '1') * ROW) + (tolower(input[2]) - 'a'));
    return mv;
}

Move get_input() {
    char input[5];
    printf("Enter the move eg='e2e4' : ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    printf("%s\n", input);
    if(strlen(input) == 4) while (getchar() != '\n'); // We clear the input buffer of garbage val to insure integrity for next iteration.
    if (check_valid_input(input)) return (Move){0X0ULL, 0x0ULL};
    return input_to_bitmap(input);
}

int check_valid_input(char* input) {
    if (input[0] > 'h' || input[0] < 'a' || input[2] > 'h' || input[2] < 'a' ||
    input[1] < '1' || input[1] > '8' || input[3] < '1' || input[3] > '8' || strlen(input) != 4) {
        puts("Enter the move in a valid format.");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

The >> index is correctly calculated but, the bit doesn't seem to shift for some particular squares like squares in rank1, rank2 and just show 0 for all of them, but are correctly shifted for other squares like h8, h7 etc.
The output looks like:
Enter the move eg='e2e4' : e2e4
e2e4
Hex: S-map: 0 E-map: 0
Enter the move eg='e2e4' : h8h7
h8h7
Hex: S-map: 1 E-map: 100
Enter the move eg='e2e4' : a1a4
a1a4
Hex: S-map: 0 E-map: 0
Enter the move eg='e2e4' : b1b4
b1b4
Hex: S-map: 0 E-map: 0
Enter the move eg='e2e4' : a2b4
a2b4
Hex: S-map: 0 E-map: 0
Enter the move eg='e2e4' : 

Any feedback will be appreciated.

The output relies on code you haven't shown.  Please update your question to include a [mcve].

Enable compiler warnings - What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?

The problem isn't in the conversion, but in the output.
In the main function, you use the following to print the converted values:
printf("Hex: S-map: %x E-map: %x\n", input.s_map, input.e_map);

The %x format specifier expects an unsigned int as its argument, but you are passing in a uint64_t which is of a different size.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior in your code.
You need to instead use the PRIx64 macro which generates the proper format specifier to print a uint64_t in hex:
printf("Hex: S-map: %" PRIx64 " E-map: %" PRIx64 "\n", input.s_map, input.e_map);


Thank you sir.  This seems to be the issue. After changing format specifiers, the expected output is shown.
